# Manytomany into notifications does not work

Tags: django

I don't really understand why when I save my model. The notification does not save the ManyToMany relationship, `exemple`. Do you have any idea?

```
def notifs_rerservationorder(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    rerservationorder = instance
    table_nb = rerservationorder.exemple.all()
    notify = Notification(rerservationorder=rerservationorder, notification_type=9)
    notify.save()
    notify.exemple.add(*table_nb)
    notify.save()

post_save.connect(notifs_rerservationorder, sender=RerservationOrder




 class Notification(models.Model):
        NOTIFICATION_TYPES = ...
    
        ...
        exemple = models.ManyToManyField('post.Exemple',blank=True, null=True, related_name='notifs_exemple')
        ...
    
    )
```

Comment: The items in a `ManyToManyField` are saved *after* saving the object itself. This is necessary, since we first need the primary key of the item before we can link it with another model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment when you save the model for the first time, the `ManyToManyField` will never contain any values. Indeed, Django *first* needs to save the record in the database before it can add items in the many-to-many relation, since it needs the primary key of the `ReservationOrder`.

You can use the [**`m2m_changed`** signal [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) which will fire if you add/remove/clear items from the many-to-many relation before or after these are saved in the database.

But [signals are often considered an *anti-pattern*](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/), since it makes it less predictable what `.save()` will do, in what order, etc. Usually it is better to encapsulate the logic in a function, and call that function in the views that will create/update the `Reservationorder`.

Comment: Well thanks I though it was save just after notify.save(). But I'll change my mind and grab the infos with the instance directly